Rxjs concatMap that resolves to switchMap
Could you please clarify what is going on here and whether this is a legitimate approach?
I have a method for fetching data. When data is fetched, I want to store it in a BehaviorSubject:
test$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[] | undefined>(undefined);

async test2$(): Promise<any[] | undefined>  {
    //...network request...
    this.test$.next([2]);
    return [2];
}

However, I am aware that the cached data may not have been fetched yet, so I must first check for the default value - undefined:
this.test$
    .pipe(
        concatMap((n) =>
            n?.length ? of(n) : from(this.test2$()).pipe(switchMap(() => this.test$))
        )
    )
    .subscribe((n) => {
        console.log('subscribe n', n);
    });

What I'm afraid of is an endless loop, which is exactly what happens without this line pipe(switchMap(() => this.test$)), but I'm not sure how the switchMap helps here.
I believe the pipe eventually resolves to this.test$ again, and all emissions to concatMap, except the first, are cancelled?

What is your goal? Are you simply trying to expose an observable that will emit the fetched data when it becomes available?

Take this approach instead :
private cache = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);

public cache$ = this.cache.asObservable().pipe(
  filter(Boolean);
);

loadData() {
  if (this.cache.value) return this.cache$.pipe(first());
  else return this.fetchData();
}

private fetchData() {
  return this.http.get('...').pipe(
    tap(res => this.cache.next(res))
  );
}

This will load the data if it's not present, otherwise it will return the cache, and either way, your subscription will not work unless there is data in the cache (thanks to the filter operator)

I thought it was a bad practice to get the subject value through .value ?

This is not a bad practice at all, especially when you use it internally (you can see that the "cache" is private, so the consumers cannot access its value) : the bad practice I can think of is to use the value instead of an async pipe in your template maybe ?

Thank you. I like your approach; it is easy to understand. I will probably use it. However, that particular case I questioned seems, despite being overly complicated, to be correct and achieve the same result as in your code?

Maybe, I haven't tested it, but my solution isn't the ONLY solution, you can find plenty more, I just simplified the approach to keep it simple and readable ! If you like yours that's not an issue at all, if this is what you are asking

Looks too complicated, you can convert the promise to an observable using from and then use share to cache the value. There is no need for the behaviour subject.
test$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[] | undefined>(undefined);

test2$(): Observable<any>  {
    return from(/* enter promise here */).pipe(
        share(),
    );
}

If you want to implement a cache, then you can also try AsyncSubject.
Article on Async Subject
const cache = {};
 
function getResource(url) {
   if (!cache[url]) {
       cache[url] = new AsyncSubject();
       fetch(url)
           .then((response) => response.json())
           .then((data) => {
               cache[url].next(data);
               cache[url].complete();
           });
   }
 
   return cache[url].asObservable();
}
 
const url = 'https://api.mocki.io/v1/ce5f60e2';
 
getResource(url).subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
 
setTimeout(() => {
   // no request is made, data is served from the AsyncSubject's cache
   getResource(url).subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
}, 3000);


@fuji You are trying to cache an api call, is that correct? First method, is the smallest code, share operator shares the original observable, so the API call is not made again and again. If you use the second approach, you can maintain a cache object, which caches the value on first call and then returns the cached value afterwards
